# Conditional compilation based on previous definition

Tags: c++11, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to write a program in C++11 that is based on `enums` to determine values for the main application. I know the following works:

```
namespace space
{
    enum class A { One, Two, Three };
}

space::A getSetting();

#define SETTING getSetting()
```

But I also want to do a conditional compile based on the first setting to determine the second setting, such as:

```
namespace space
{
    enum class A { One, Two, Three };
    enum class B { Red, Blue, Yellow };
    enum class C { Black, White };
    enum class D { Green, Orange };
}

space::A getSettingA();
space::B getSettingB();
space::C getSettingC();
space::D getSettingD();

#define SETTING_ONE getSettingA()
#if SETTING_ONE == A::One
    #define SETTING_TWO getSettingB()
#elif SETTING_ONE == A::Two
    #define SETTING_TWO getSettingC()
#else
    #define SETTING_TWO getSettingD()
#endif
```

This provides a compiler warning of "C4067: unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline". I did some research and found that I can't use the scope operator `::` in a preprocessor directive, but is there a way to do this kind of conditional compile?

EDIT: I'm basically looking for a way to use one variable for several different `enums`, like an opaque data type. Using the `#define` was the simplest solution. I use the resulting settings in the same way, so I didn't want to have to keep track of which specific enumeration I was using, just have a single name by which to call whatever setting.

DEPRECATED: I've decided to find a different solution to my problem and am no longer seeking an answer to this question.

Comment: The value of `getSettingA()` can only be determined at run time. How do you expect the compiler to learn it at compile time - with a time machine? Also, how do you plan to use `SETTING_TWO` (assuming you managed to define it somehow)? Can you show an example? It may have one of a few different types, basically unpredictably.

Comment: Also, do you rely on `"#SETTING_TWO"` to be `"getSettingB()"` and so on? Too vague question for my taste

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I use the same format for each of the settings, but the values in the `enums` differ one from the next. I don't rely on `SETTING_TWO` to be any specific enum because they are all used identically. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong : **#if SETTING_ONE == A::One**

you can't do this with preprocessor.

With templates I would try something like traits.

```
enum{
    One = 58,Two = 54, Red = 65, //...
};
struct A{
    static int value1 = One;
    static int value2 = Two;
};
struct B{
    static int value1 = Red;
    static int value2 = Blue;
};

template <typename T>
struct setting_T{
    static int value1 = T::value1;
    static int value2 = T::value2;
};

typedef setting_T<A> setting; // this is you choice for this compilation (you could use B)
```

To use it :

```
setting::value1 /* this is A::value1*/
```

Comment: I'm aware the code doesn't work as is. I'm looking for a way to do that kind of conditional compile.

Comment: you can not with an enum. Maybe template?

Comment: Can you provide an example using a template?

Comment: could you show me how you want to use it (in your code) I mean the result of this setting

Comment: I would like to be able to use it as I would the `enum` behind the `#define`. So, instead of using `space::B::Red`, I use `SETTING_TWO`, since `SETTING_TWO` could be any of three different `enums`. I then use a `toString()` function to get the name and open the proper .xml file.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks for the help, though. I'll just come up with something else than what I'm trying. It's more trouble than it's worth.